# Find a specific text on a button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I have the following button.

```
<button class="btn-standard buyButton currency-coins">Buy Now for 3k <button>
```

I want to find if the button contains "Buy Now".
I used something like this, but it didn't work.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Buy Now"]').click()
```

Comment: What does _but it didn't work_ mean? Have you tried reading the documentation for what I presume is Selenium (since your question doesn't contain that information, I can only guess)

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Buy Now"]').click()` this one didn't work:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete innerText is **Buy Now for 3k**. So to identify and click on the element through partial innerText i.e. **Buy Now** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) set for the desired [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) and can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `contains()`

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'Buy Now')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `starts-with()`

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[starts-with(., 'Buy Now')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I get the following error: `StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <button class="btn-standard buyButton currency-coins"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
`

Comment: I forgot to mention, the 'buy button' appears after a click of a button. ex: I press click on a button and after 1 second appear "Buy button'

Comment: @PaulVio Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Yes, it's working man. Thank you. But can you explain to me what means webdriverwait and that "EC" in 2-3 words?

Comment: @PaulVio Updated the answer with all the required references. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204817/discussion-between-paul-vio-and-debanjanb).